# Dynamic GUI based on serial input C#

Tags: c#, user-interface

I have an application that, based on serial input (like a specific HEX code), displays different windows form.

The structure of the form is basically the same for every form but I have to display different textboxes (or similar input boxes) that the user has to complete for each form.

Every textbox is for a different command so, with the GUI, changes also the command that I have to send via serial.

Which is the best approach for doing this? Creating multiple windows form files and open the right one based on the serial input or create dynamically the form?

Comment: `that the user have to compile for each form` can application users define their own forms? In that case you have no choice but to programmatically generate them.

Comment: The forms are predefined. For example for product 1, product 2, ..., product n. The user have only to insert data

Comment: OP means `that the user has to complete`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you wish to listen to a serial port and display different forms on screen depending on what characters are received on the serial port. The user will then enter data into the form that is displayed on screen.

Both of the approaches you suggest will work, but if you are working in WinForms I suggest that you will find it easiest to create a main form and multiple child forms. The main form can contain your serial port and all the logic for listening and controlling which entry forms are visible. The main form can then `Show` or `Hide` other forms as needed.

You should be able to test this approach in just a few minutes and the visual designer will do most of the work for you, which is why I suggest that it will be easier than creating the forms dynamically.